# How to update Material-UI table with Mobx / Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, mobx

I need to update a Material-UI table with a MobX store that fetches from Firebase. So far, the table updates the 'symbol' column with Firebase data, but the other columns are generic.

[image: my table]

```
let id = 0;
function createData(symbol, date, cost, quote, pl) {
  id += 1;
  console.log(symbol, date, cost, quote, pl)
  return { id, symbol, date, cost, quote, pl };
}

var returnArr = [];
export function getOpenTrades(user){
  db.ref('/users/' +user+ '/mocktrades/holdings/').once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      console.log('childSnapshot',childSnapshot.val()) //   <----------- shown below 
      let newData = createData(childSnapshot.key, '01012001', 0.01, 100, 100-0.01)
      returnArr.push(newData);
    })
  })
  console.log('returnArr',returnArr)
  return(
      returnArr
  )
}
```

[image]

Please help me directly access the dateOpened, priceOpened, and quantity. As you can see, the symbol is referenced with childSnapshot.key. These other three items are inside a push; can we access that push id with something like .next() ... instead of having to know what the push id is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do a forEach on the childSnapshot:

```
let id = 0;
function createData(symbol, date, cost, quote, pl) {
  id += 1;
  console.log(symbol, date, cost, quote, pl)
  return { id, symbol, date, cost, quote, pl };
}



var returnArr = [];
export function getOpenTrades(user){
  db.ref('/users/' +user+ '/mocktrades/holdings/').once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

      childSnapshot.forEach(function(item) {
        var itemVal = item.val()
        let newData = createData(childSnapshot.key, itemVal.dateOpened, itemVal.priceOpened, 100, 100-itemVal.priceOpened)
        returnArr.push(newData);
      })
    })
  })
  console.log('returnArr',returnArr)
  return(
      returnArr
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
createData(childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.dateOpened, childSnapshot.priceOpened, childSnapshot.quantity);
```

Comment: Tried it. childSnapshot.dateOpened, childSnapshot.priceOpened childSnapshot.quantity are empty because they are a level deeper. How to access that deeper level?